# Selecting an element within an element with different ID names or class name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an unordered list that has tables in it. The list also uses an image which when clicked on should hide the table. I have the following jQuery code, but it is not working:

```
$(".glyphicon-remove").click(function () {
        var tblId = $(this).attr("id");
       // alert(tblId);
       var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this table?");
       if(ans == true)
        $("#" + tblId).hide();
    });
```

and the list used is as follows:

```
<ul class="sortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default"  id="first"><span style="float:right;"class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span><br/>




            <table class="rounded-corner">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Details</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>User</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Box Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>45$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Trial Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>155$</td>
            <td>12/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Carrina</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Hosting Pack</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>45$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Duo Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>745$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Alex</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Alavasti Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>45$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="" /></td>
            <td>Box Software</td>
            <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</td>
            <td>45$</td>
            <td>10/04/2011</td>
            <td>web design</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/edit.png" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td>
            <td><a href="#"><img src="images/trash.gif" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a></td
        </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="second">2</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="third">3</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="fourth">4</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="fifth">5</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="sixth">6</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="seventh">7</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="eighth">8</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="ninth">9</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default" id="tenth">10</li>

        </ul>
```

Please help me out.

Comment: I think you should remove `#` from here `$("#" + tblId).hide();`

Comment: <span style="float:right;"class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>

Span does not conatin any Id attribute.

So this line : 
var tblId = $(this).attr("id");
tblId always comes as undefined.

Comment: Paste this in your `if` statement: `$(this).parent().find('table').hide();`

Comment: `$(this).closest('li').hide()` is also work, I think...

Comment: @Bharadwaj it will hide `<li>` also, but OP want's to hide only the `table` inside specific `<li>`

Comment: @Pavlo then the accepted answer is wrong! He is hiding `li`.

Comment: @Bharadwaj Yes, you are correct. The correct answer should be provided from Milind Anantwar. But if OP accepted the wrong answer, assume he wanted to hide `li` element as well, thus the OP's question is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
var tblId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
```

instead of:

```
var tblId = $(this).attr("id");
```

since you want to get the `id` of `li` element not `span` with class `glyphicon-remove`

Comment: `$(this).closest('li').hide()` can be used?

Comment: how do I get the hidden tables back?

Comment: @UtkarshSingh you can use `.toggle()` instead of `.hide()` - thus clicking on your `<span>` element again your table will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".glyphicon-remove").click(function () {
    var tblId = $(this).attr("id");
   // alert(tblId);
   var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this table?");
   if(ans == true)
    $(this).siblings('table').hide();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sMV52/1/)**